# Demander l'heure

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques

Je connais trois manières de demander l'heure :

- Vous avez l’heure ?
- Quelle heure est-il ? (formel)
- Il est quelle heure ? (informel)

Lors d'une promenade au parc, quelqu'un m'a posé la question :

-Vous avez le temps ?

J'avais un peu surpris en me demandant si la personne demande l'heure ou si je porte une montre. La tournure est-elle gauche ou non ? Quelle est sa signification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personnellement j'utilise "quelle heure est-il" à chaque fois. "Vous avez le temps" ou "avez-vous le temps" serait plutôt utilisé pour:

> Avez-vous le temps de répondre à un sondage ?

et d'une manière générale, demander si la personne serait prête à prendre de son temps pour faire quelque chose. Aucun rapport avec demander l'heure dans ce cas.

De mon point de vue, "avez-vous le temps" (plus correct que "vous avez le temps" quand il s'agit d'une question) est une tournure incorrecte quand il s'agit de demander l'heure à quelqu'un.

Comment: On ne dit en effet jamais *vous avez le temps* pour demander l'heure mais attention, le français oral n'est pas "incorrect", il suit simplement d'autres règles et usages que le français académique et soutenu.